# Customize Eclipse Code Assist

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile

I have an existing c project, that is makefile based, that I have brought into Eclipse C/C++(Mars Release (4.5.0)). I am able to build successfully within Eclipse, but the problem I'm facing is the project supports targeting several different architectures, my makefile handles linking the appropriate architecture specific headers but eclipse doesn't know about it so I get lots of undefined types.

For example the processessor specific types:

```
UINTN
UINT8
UINT32
etc..
```

Are all defined in processor specific header files. Located in:

```
\Include\X64
\Include\AArch64
\Include\Arm
\Include\IA32 
etc..
```

I know that I am targeting x64, therefore I know that the header I want to use is in the `\Include\x64\` directory. But I cant figure out how to tell eclipse to use the definitions for its code assist. As all of the `'Include'` folders are in the source, it sees all of them and cant decide what to do. So while my code builds its got red squiggly lines everywhere about unresolvable types.

In Visual Studio I had done Intellisense -> Include Search Path -> And I added the \Include\X64 folder there and it resolved my issue. But I haven't been able to find the equivalent behavior in Eclipse.

Thanks!

EDIT: If anyone is willing/wanting to try this on the real source im talking about, it is the UEFI EDK2 source: `> git clone https://github.com/tianocore/edk2`
When you open it in eclipse check out

```
\MdeModulePkg\Application\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.c
```

That's the sample app it comes with, and you will see eclipse cant resolve UINT32. Since its targeting IA32 by default configuration, the include file you want is `'\MdePkg\Include\IA32\ProcessorBind.h'`. But despite adding that directory, and the file specifically to the eclipse CDT include directory it still wont resolve those types

EDIT2:

I have gone so far as to remove all the other architecture include directories, so all that's left is x64. That didn't help.

I then went further and in the helloworld.c sample application I `#included <ProcessorBind.h>` Which is the file that has all of the missing definitions. Eclipse understands the include, if I right click and say 'Open Declaration' it opens the x64\ProcessorBind.h yet it still cant resolve the types... help.. [image]

Comment: Are you aware of `stdint.h`? And: is that C or C++? There is no language "C/C++".

Comment: yes, but this is targeting an embedded device. No libc.

Comment: `stdint.h` is required by any implementation since C99. That is one of the [few headers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p6) also available for _freestanding implementations_. It uses no library, btw.

Comment: I appreciate the information, I learned something new today. But it doesn't help with my problem. The various sized ints is just one off many processor specific items defined in the include\x64 folder. I still need to figure out how to make the IDE process the headers in the 'include\x64' folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While technically I don't have a solution for my original problem. I installed KDevelop (its Linux only) and its intellisense/index what ever you want to call it worked the way I wanted. At first it had some conflicts, so it asked if I wanted to add custom include paths. I did, and added the x64 folder. Then it all worked as expected.

So for others struggling with the same thing, if your on Linux, just switch to kdevelop.

Answer (score 1):

Under your project settings (right click project and select Properties), navigate to C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc. Select GNU C from the side option (repeat these same steps for C++ if you have any C++ code using these headers). Select CDT User Setting Entires and click Add on the right.

[image]

Select Include Directory for the type and click the folder icon to browse to the correct folder. Then hit OK.

[image]

CDT should automatically rebuild the index. If it doesn't for some reason (it can be a bit finicky sometimes) right click your project and select Index -> Rebuild.

Comment: This sounds right but it didn't fix it. I forced it to rebuild the index. I tried various permutations of the check boxe's on the add page (Contains System Headers, Built-ins) but that didn't seem to affect it. This feels like the right place to add this... I added 'Include\X64\ path to the GNU C CDT

Comment: Added more detail to my question to show the exact open source project im trying to get working

Comment: I tried out the code you pointed to and see the issue. It looks like my method only works for macro defines (which is why I use it). I think CDT is confused by the multiple definitions. I've found the things in CDT that lead to errors (like unknown type) are a bit too buggy for use in a large code base, so I tend to turn them off.

Comment: I appreciate you trying out the code base. Any other ideas how we can get this to work? I event went so far as to delete all the other architectures and specifically include the x64 header I needed and it still wouldn't resolve the types

Comment: It seems like a bug with CDT. I would try to hit up their mailing list/forum or maybe file a bug.